# Duplicate object going into an array React.js, Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

First of all the goal is to display cars from a database on a React website, sounds simple enough, right?

I have a Firestore database that has cars in it, it looks like this:
[image]

I also have a useState hook that looks like this:

```
   type car = {
    carId: string;
    model: string;
    image: string;
  };
  const [cars, setCars]: [Array<car>, any] = React.useState([]); // update
```

I am getting data from the Firestore database and all is going well, except that cars from the database get added to the cars hook even though I am checking if it already exists:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Get cars from firestore database and set them with setCars
    (async () => {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "cars"));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // Check if car is already in the array
        for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
          if (cars[i].carId === doc.data().carId) {
            console.log("Car already in array");
            return;
          }
        }
        console.table(doc.data());
        setCars((cars: any) => [...cars, doc.data()]);
      });
    })();
  }, []);
```

In the end `cars` useState will still end up looking like this:
[image]

Any help/tips much appreciated!

Comment: Try using the exist method from arrays . you don't have to check only for id . simpler code => less prone to break

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way to check if the element already exists and see if the problem still persists.

```
const documentData = doc.data();
const newArray = cars.filter(const car => car.carId === documentData.carId)
if(newArray.length > 0) return;
setCars(previousCars => [...previousCars, documentData]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve it.
Still multiple of the same car are added the to the array.
I found out that the useEffect hook is called twice because React strict mode is on.
Turning off React strict mode has temporarily solved this issue, but I'm still confused as to why the cars are added to the array... Maybe related to it being an async function?

Answer (score 0):

The `return` inside your `if` condition breaks from the immediate `for` loop, meaning when it compares the first record, it matches and since item exists, that for loop breaks and the program continues on to add the car data.

What you want instead, is to simply check if the new doc.data() exists in your cars list, which you could do by:

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // Check if car is already in the array
        if(!cars.find(carItem => carItem.carId === doc.data().carId){
           console.table(doc.data());
           setCars((cars: any) => [...cars, doc.data()]);
        }
      });
```